# How to eliminate Storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

I have an iPhone app in the store that I used xCode 4.2 and Storyboards to create.  I now wish for iOS 4.3, and prior, users to be able to use the app... they currently cannot due to the storyboard.

How do I proceed to eliminate the storyboard to gain a wider audience?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do this, unfortunately. What I would suggest is to manually copy the elements of each segue in your storyboard and paste them each one at a time to a newly created nib file...

Also, dont forget if you go the multiple nibs way, you'll need to edit a bit your AppDelegate and create a MainWindow.nib file. Create a new project using nib files to have a perfect exemple of what to do!